NetworkManager and switching dns but not the default route
I'd like the VPN connection to switch the default DNS on the system, but not the default route. I was hoping these options will do the trick:
ipv4.method:                            auto
ipv4.dns-priority:                      -1
ipv4.ignore-auto-dns:                   no
ipv4.never-default:                     yes

(I've also tried setting ipv4.dns: 172.30.0.1 explicitly)
But resolvectl status still shows only the main interface having any dns configured and used by default. I have to run resolvectl dns tun0 172.30.0.1 and resolvectl default-route tun0 by hand to achieve what I want.
How do I use NetworkManager to achieve this automatically?
